# SQLite check if subquery gives same answers as other subquery

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to construct query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 AS t1 WHERE (
    (SELECT column2 FROM table1 WHERE column1=t1.column1)!=(SELECT column2 FROM table1 WHERE column1=1)
)
```

But the problem is that SQLite checks only first results of subqueries.

I mean that if `SELECT column2 FROM table1 WHERE column1=t1.column1` gives following results: `(1,2,3)` and `SELECT column2 FROM table1 WHERE column1=1` gives `(1,2,3,4)` SQLite will check only `1!=1`, not `(1,2,3)!=(1,2,3,4)`.

I need to filter rows where prevoius two queries give only same rows (i.e. `(1,2,3)` from the first and `(1,2,3)` from the second)

The example of my table:

```
id | column1 | column2 | ...
1  |       1 |       1 | ...
2  |       1 |       2 | ...
3  |       1 |       3 | ...
4  |       2 |       1 | ...
5  |       2 |       2 | ...
6  |       2 |       3 | ...
7  |       2 |       4 | ...
8  |       3 |       1 | ...
9  |       3 |       2 | ...
10 |       3 |       3 | ...
```

And I need to get rows from `id=4` to `id=7` because it has `7  |       2 |       4 | ...` row (for one column1 value there are not same column2 values as in column1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [compound select statements](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound): subtract the subqueries from each other and check if any row is left:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 AS t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT column2 FROM table1 WHERE column1=t1.column1
              EXCEPT
              SELECT column2 FROM table1 WHERE column1=1)
   OR EXISTS (SELECT column2 FROM table1 WHERE column1=1
              EXCEPT
              SELECT column2 FROM table1 WHERE column1=t1.column1)
```

Alternatively, do a similar operation with individual rows: the subqueries are different if some row does not have a counterpart in the other subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 AS t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT column2
              FROM table1 AS t2
              WHERE column1 = t1.column1
                AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                FROM table1 AS t3
                                WHERE column2 = t2.column2
                                  AND column1 = 1))
   OR EXISTS (SELECT column2
              FROM table1 AS t2
              WHERE column1 = 1
                AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                FROM table1 AS t3
                                WHERE column2 = t2.column2
                                  AND column1 = t1.column1))
```

(The second query might be more efficient if you have the requisite indexes.)